# How to add mimetype (video/webm) and codec (vp9) to the blob object before sending to server

Tags: javascript, video, server, webrtc, blob

**Am recording video using webrtc and send each 10 seconds video as blob to server, and all 10 seconds files are getting saved on server, till now everything is fine but only problem is only first video file is getting played as video rest other files are not getting played since it is missing codec and MIMEType. please help me how to send each 10 seconds blob with mimetype and wit codec vp9**

```
// This code is adapted from
// https://rawgit.com/Miguelao/demos/master/mediarecorder.html

'use strict';

/* globals MediaRecorder */

const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', handleSourceOpen, false);
let mediaRecorder;
let recordedBlobs;
let sourceBuffer;

const errorMsgElement = document.querySelector('span#errorMsg');
const recordedVideo = document.querySelector('video#recorded');
const recordButton = document.querySelector('button#record');
recordButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (recordButton.textContent === 'Start Recording') {
    startRecording();
  } else {
    stopRecording();
    recordButton.textContent = 'Start Recording';
    playButton.disabled = false;
    downloadButton.disabled = false;
  }
});

const playButton = document.querySelector('button#play');
playButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const superBuffer = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {type: 'video/webm'});
  recordedVideo.src = null;
  recordedVideo.srcObject = null;
  recordedVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(superBuffer);
  recordedVideo.controls = true;
  recordedVideo.play();
  console.log('start- display recordedblob');
  console.log(recordedVideo);
  console.log('end- display recordedblob');
});

const downloadButton = document.querySelector('button#download');
downloadButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const blob = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {type: 'video/webm'});
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.style.display = 'none';
  a.href = url;
  a.download = 'test.webm';
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.removeChild(a);
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }, 100);
});

function handleSourceOpen(event) {
  console.log('MediaSource opened');
  sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vp8"');
  console.log('Source buffer: ', sourceBuffer);
}

function handleDataAvailable(event) {
  console.log('handleDataAvailable', event);
  console.log('shree sai baba', event.data);
  if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
    recordedBlobs.push(event.data);
    console.log('heyy'+recordedBlobs);



// to save video as each blob

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('video', event.data);
    console.log('result blob which am trying to send to server', event.data);

    // Execute the ajax request, in this case we have a very simple PHP script
    // that accepts and save the uploaded "video" file
    xhr('/webcam/', formData, function (fName) {
        console.log("video successfully uploaded !");

    });

    // Helper function to send
    function xhr(url, data, callback) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                callback(location.href + request.responseText);
            }
        };
        request.open('POST', url);
        request.send(data);
        console.log(data);
        console.log('logg')
        console.log(request.response);
    }

        console.log('10 seconds video sent to the server');

// end of save video as each

  }
}


function startRecording() {
  recordedBlobs = [];
  let options = {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9'};


  if (!MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(options.mimeType)) {
    console.error(`${options.mimeType} is not Supported`);
    errorMsgElement.innerHTML = `${options.mimeType} is not Supported`;
    options = {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp8'};
    if (!MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(options.mimeType)) {
      console.error(`${options.mimeType} is not Supported`);
      errorMsgElement.innerHTML = `${options.mimeType} is not Supported`;
      options = {mimeType: 'video/webm'};
      if (!MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(options.mimeType)) {
        console.error(`${options.mimeType} is not Supported`);
        errorMsgElement.innerHTML = `${options.mimeType} is not Supported`;
        options = {mimeType: ''};
      }
    }
  }

  try {
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(window.stream, options);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Exception while creating MediaRecorder:', e);
    errorMsgElement.innerHTML = `Exception while creating MediaRecorder: ${JSON.stringify(e)}`;
    return;
  }

  console.log('Created MediaRecorder', mediaRecorder, 'with options', options);
  recordButton.textContent = 'Stop Recording';
  playButton.disabled = true;
  downloadButton.disabled = true;
  mediaRecorder.onstop = (event) => {
    console.log('Recorder stopped: ', event);

    console.log('naduuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuzz');
    console.log('Recorded Blobss: ', recordedBlobs);



    console.log('ans', recordedBlobs);
  //  console.log(Blob.arrayBuffer())

    console.log('Recorded Blobss: ', recordedBlobs.type);
    console.log('naduuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu');


  };
  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
  mediaRecorder.start(10000); // collect 10s of data
  console.log('MediaRecorder started', mediaRecorder);
}

function stopRecording() {
  mediaRecorder.stop();
}

function handleSuccess(stream) {
  recordButton.disabled = false;
  console.log('getUserMedia() got stream:', stream);
  window.stream = stream;

  const gumVideo = document.querySelector('video#gum');
  gumVideo.srcObject = stream;
}

async function init(constraints) {
  try {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
    handleSuccess(stream);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('navigator.getUserMedia error:', e);
    errorMsgElement.innerHTML = `navigator.getUserMedia error:${e.toString()}`;
  }
}

document.querySelector('button#start').addEventListener('click', async () => {
  const hasEchoCancellation = document.querySelector('#echoCancellation').checked;
  const constraints = {
    audio: {
      echoCancellation: {exact: hasEchoCancellation}
    },
    video: {
      width: 720, height: 480
    }
  };
  console.log('Using media constraints:', constraints);
  await init(constraints);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'video/webm');
```

Comment: Hey @kenji tanaka if i use setRequestHeader('Content-Type');  I get error for posting through xhr as 500